# Rails 4 does not render my Layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I currently mindblown regarding Layouts in Rails 4, as of now, i created a layout for my controller and it is successfully being called in my controller using the `layout "layout_name"`

but the problem is, whenever i redirect_to that controller it only renders the page itself not the layout on top of it.

here is my snipper of the code:

```
class LoginController < ApplicationController
  layout "login_layout"
  def index
    user = User.new
  end

  def login_user
    validate_credential = User.login(params[:user])
    if validate_credential[0] == true
      session[:user_firstname] = validate_credential[1][0]["firstname"].capitalize
      session[:user_lastname] = validate_credential[1][0]["lastname"].capitalize
      session[:user_id] = validate_credential[1][0]["id"]
      session[:advisory_class] = validate_credential[1][0]["advisory_class"].capitalize
      redirect_to :controller=> 'dashboard', :action=> 'home'
    else
      redirect_to :action=>'index'
    end
  end
```

Take not the redirect_to in my login_user function does render the layout.

and this is my code of the logout (from another controller)

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  layout 'dashboard_layout'
  def home
  end

  def settings
  end

  def students
  end

  def logout
    session.clear
    redirect_to :controller=>'login',:action=>'index'
  end
```

It renders the page itself but the layout for that controller is not included.

I've searched many solution but still, no hopes.

This is a pic of how the root_path looks like when being called (redirect_to) from my dashboard controller.

[image]

and this must be the design of my root_path. (Layout included).
Take note that the URL is the same but the layout is not being rendered. but when i refresh the page it shows the layout.

[image]

Comment: which layout is rendered in each case? which layout do you want rendered in each case?

Comment: Bear in mind that `redirect_to` always creates a new request. Thus, which layout will be used, depends upon which controller the new request will head to.

Comment: as far as i know. if the controller is being called. it will render the layout of that controller? is that right?. i was trying to call the login controller that has login_layout. but it does not render the login_layout

Comment: I've edited the post, please see the pictures included showing that the layout is not being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, it is Turbolinks. i removed turbolinks in my application.js and gem file and it worked like a charm. the layout does not change because the CSS of the particular layout that is being called is not changing. when the app redirects to login controller the css must be login.self?etc.etc. but it stays as the dashboard's css.